# How to make plots scaling consistent when running a series of simulations?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

In my function it returns a plot of my data, say example, using ListLinePlot, and this is the size I obtain:

[image]

[image]

but when running a series of simulations inside a Table:

Table[tCorrStudentsT[i]=sensStudentsT[sensMat[[i]], mcRun,chrT,hrT,ppT,r] ,{i,10}]

the resultant graphs look like these, without manually adjusting each graph after simulation is complete?

[image]

so how can I set it such that the series of graphs will be consistent with my single simulation result plot size?

Comment: Its better to post code rather than images.

Comment: Say a function I run once returns a window size of 200 x 200 pixels in size, is there a way to make the same window size of any plots when running the same function inside a Table loop, as it is hard to see the same result on a different scaling each time when I run different number of the same functions.

Comment: As you insist on posting code as an image, which makes it non-copyable, and you refuse to learn how to format your questions, I'm voting to close as not a real question. In addition to the down vote, of course.

Answer (score 5):

```
p = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}, ImageSize -> 200]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
size = ImageSize /. FullOptions[p];
Table[Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}, ImageSize -> size], {6}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Hi Nasser, is this a pre or post simulation option? It is because I have already ran my long simulations and prefer not to rerun these again.

Comment: Hi Nasser, so inside my functionPlot: p=ListLinePlot[...]; size=ImageSize /. FullOptions[p] (plotting it once) and then when called by Table using Table[  functionPlot[], {i,6}, ImageSize -> pSize]. This gives me error of pSize at position 3 does not have the correct form for an iterator? Also size is still Automatic? I made size to be global as opposed to local variable.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to suggest that if you had generated simulations/plots, you could reset the graphics options with `Show`:

Sims + incorrect plots:

```
sims = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 200}];
plots = ListLinePlot[#,
  PlotLabel -> Style["Gaussian copula to 1st default spreads", FontSize -> 18]] & /@ sims
```

Reset options:

```
Show[#, PlotLabel -> Style["Gaussian copula to 1st default spreads", 
     FontSize -> Scaled[0.06]], ImageSize -> 800] & /@ plots
```

The only problem is that when I use a relative font size `Scaled[0.06]`, which rescales nicely if you change the size of the image or use `Export`, extra white space is inserted around the graph, especially on the sides and sometimes on top.

Nasser is right about using `ImageSize` to control the image's size.  Sometimes you have to use `ImagePadding`, too, if the ticks change width (because of a different number of digits or minus signs that come & go).